# How to check if the product is downloadable?

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework, magento2

I would like to check if the product is downloadable and has no weight so I can check it besides if the product isSaleable to solve a bug.

This is the check that I want to add condition to it

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a product is a downloadable product, you have to check the type of the product. You [can see how this is implemented in the internal admin panel widget](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable.php), and should be able to adapt it to your own template:

```
if ($_product->isSaleable() && ($_product->getTypeId() == \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE)):
```

Comment: if I want to check condition if the product has no weight

Comment: That is available through `getWeight()` on `$_product` as well.